# Create word document from template from Excel when word isn't open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel file that generates some graphics, and I am trying to create a report in Word that pulls some of these graphics.  I have everything set up and working, but the Word file isn't generated unless Word is already open.  This is a snippet of what I have so far - what am I missing?

```
Sub Generate_Report()
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim templateFile As Object
On Error Resume Next

' Define template word file
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'gives error 429 if Word is not open
If Err = 429 Then
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'creates a Word application
    ' wordapp.Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\WeatherShift_Report_Template.docm"
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Err.Clear
End If

Set templateFile = wordApp.Documents.Add(template:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\WeatherShift_Report_Template.docm")

' Copy charts to new word file
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
With templateFile.Bookmarks
    .Item("dbT_dist_line").Range.Paste
End With
```

Comment: Whenever you use `On Error Resume Next` you should also have an `On Error GoTo 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `On Error Resume Next` may be masking a later error.

Try this:

```
Sub Generate_Report()

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim templateFile As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'gives error 429 if Word is not open
    On Error Goto 0 'stop ignoring errors
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'creates a Word application
    End If

    wordApp.Visible = True '<< edit

    Set templateFile = wordApp.Documents.Add(template:=ThisWorkbook.Path _
                                      & "\WeatherShift_Report_Template.docm")

    ' Copy charts to new word file
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 18").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    With templateFile.Bookmarks
        .Item("dbT_dist_line").Range.Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but that didn't do it.  I still have to manually open Word before it will work.

Comment: But you get no error at all?  Try moving the `.Visible` out of the `If` block - see my edit.  If you have a running instance but it's hidden then you need to make sure it get unhidden.

Comment: OK I think that did it (an no, I never had any errors, it just didn't open).  But now, and this should probably be a new question, but it opens several identical copies of the same word file.  That last little chunk in the code: Sheets -> End with, is actually repeated 9 times.  Is that causing it to open a word file multiple times?

Comment: I would start by going into Task Manager and making sure all instances of Word are closed: after running your previous code you may still have random instances of word running.  Then start degugging from there...